# glide and picasso cannot load a picture by url

Tags: android, imageview, picasso, android-glide

I have a link

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/mediaviewer/rm746868224
```

I need to download this picture by neither Glide nor Picasso can help me. They both return error. Examples how I use them

```
        Glide.with(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()))
            .load(movieDetails.getImage())
            .fitCenter()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.wait_button)
            .error(R.drawable.error_download)
            .into(image);

    Picasso.get()
            .load(movieDetails.getImage())
            .fit()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.wait_button)
            .error(R.drawable.error_download)
            .into(image);
```

image - is my target ImageView
What do I do wrong? Or problem is in the url?
How can I download this pic by Glide or Picasso?
I have another type of url in my project and all of them end with ....jpg and everything is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url is not to download the image. This https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/mediaviewer/rm746868224 is not a valid url for poster image.

Instead you need to parse the html and get the required image url.

In the html you have the below and the url is in a meta tag

```
 <meta itemprop="image" content="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_QL50_SY500_CR0,0,352,500_AL_.jpg">
```

For the url provided you can parse and get the link by parsing html using jsoup parser.

Add the below to your app build.gradle file

```
 implementation group: 'org.jsoup', name: 'jsoup', version: '1.12.1'
```

Use asynctask doInBackground

```
  Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/mediaviewer/rm746868224");
  Element  meta = document.select("meta[itemprop=image]").first()
  String image_url = meta.attr("content")
```

In onPostEecute

```
   Glide.with(context).load(url) // url is the one returned in doInbackground
            .override(100, 200) // provide some width and height. glide will automatically scale the image down appropriately
            .into(image);
```

Note: I guess there is api available from imdb to get poster images but i think its a paid licensed one. Not sure about the legality stuff.

Similarly you can parse other tags under html and get the required information.

Also i checked with a different url such as https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068647/mediaviewer/rm2109407488 the meta has the image url. So this can be used for other urls as well.

Comment: thanx! I looked for it. but where did you take this string   <meta itemprop="image" content="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_QL50_SY500_CR0,0,352,500_AL_.jpg">

Comment: By inspecting the html with chrome developer tools. You can also try jsoup online by fetching the content with just url

Answer (score 1):

this is the link you should be trying
[Godfather](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BM2MyNjYxNmUtYTAwNi00MTYxLWJmNWYtYzZlODY3ZTk3OTFlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzkwMjQ5NzM@._V1_QL50_SY1000_CR0,0,704,1000_AL_.jpg)
instead of

```
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/mediaviewer/rm746868224
```

Comment: I understand what do you mean. Maybe you know - how can I receive this link automatically?

Comment: @Kirguduck it seems the link is not for image. I thought it was because the image size was large. You can get the actual url by right clicking on the browse and inspect element. Other way is to parse html for the url and get the required poster url and then glide will load properly

Comment: @Kirguduck i posted a way to get the url of the poster by html parsing using jsoup.

Comment: You can you jsoup to parse the html and scrape out the original image link.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Glide.with(mContext)
                .load("https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/mediaviewer/rm746868224.jpg")
                .apply(new RequestOptions().diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).fitCenter())
                .into(image);
```